# Django - When is a query made?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I want to minimize the number of database queries my application makes, and I am familiarizing myself more with Django's ORM.  I am wondering, what are the cases where a query is executed.

For instance, this format is along the lines of the answer I'm looking for (for example purposes, not accurate to my knowledge):

- Model.objects.get()

  - Always launches a query
- Model.objects.filter()

  - Launches a query if objects is empty only
- (...)

I am assuming curried filter operations never make additional requests, but from the docs it looks like filter() does indeed make database requests if it's the first thing called.

Comment: You mentioned you are about to minimize the number of queries. If your application involves dealing with object hierarchies a lot (foreign key, one-to-one, many-to-many relationships, etc.) you could benefit from [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using test cases, you can use this custom assertion included in django's `TestCase`: [assertNumQueries()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.assertNumQueries).

Example:

```
with self.assertNumQueries(2):
    x = SomeModel.objects.get(pk=1)
    y = x.some_foreign_key_in_object
```

If the expected number of queries was wrong, you'd see an assertion failed message of the form:

```
Num queries (expected - actual):
    2 : 5
```

In this example, the foreign key would cause an additional query even though there's no explicit query (get, filter, exclude, etc.).

For this reason, I would use a practical approach: Test or logging, instead of trying to learn each of the cases in which django is supposed to query.

---

If you don't use unit tests, you may use this other method which prints the actual SQL statements sent by django, so you can have an idea of the complexity of the query, and not just the number of queries:

(`DEBUG` setting must be set to `True`)

```
from django.db import connection

x = SomeModel.objects.get(pk=1)
y = x.some_foreign_key_in_object

print connection.queries
```

The print would show a dictionary of queries:

```
[
 {'sql': 'SELECT a, b, c, d ... FROM app_some_model', 'time': '0.002'},
 {'sql': 'SELECT j, k, ... FROM app_referenced_model JOIN ... blabla ', 
      'time': '0.004'}
]
```

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running) on `connection.queries`.

Of course, you can also combine both methods and use the `print connection.queries` in your test cases.

Answer (score 2):

See Django's documentation on when querysets are evaluated: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated

Evaluation in this case means that the query is executed. This mostly happens when you are trying to access the results, eg. when calling `list()` or `len()` on it or iterating over the results.

`get()`in your example doesn't return a queryset but a model objects, therefore it is evaluated immediately.